# I'm having problem handling Error from rust postgres::Error

Tags: postgresql, rust, serde

I'm not able to properly handle `postgres::Error`. using SqlState or DbError didn't help.
postgres::error seems to leave a little room to properly handle error or I'm missing something.

```rs
extern crate postgres;
use postgres::{Client, NoTls};
use postgres::error::Error as PgError;

        
 pub async fn get_metadata(client: &Client, db: String, schema: String) -> Result<serde_json::Value, PgError> {

    let query = r#"
        select row_to_json(Tb) as tbls from(
        . . . .         
        WHERE table_schema=$1) Tb;
    "#;

    // Execute the query and collect the results
    let rows = client.query(query, &[&schema])?;

    // Assuming you expect only one row as a result
    if let Some(row) = rows.iter().next() {
        // Extract the JSON response from the "tbls" column
        let json_response: Option<serde_json::Value> = row.get(0);

        
        // You can now work with the JSON response
        match json_response {
            Some(json) => {
                return Ok(json);
            }
            None => {
                eprintln!("No JSON response found in the result.");
                // Return an error here
                return Err(_);
            }
        }
    }

    // Return an error if no row is found
    Err(PgError.into_source())
}
```

I'm greeted with this error:

```
error[E0061]: this function takes 1 argument but 0 arguments were supplied
   --> src/main.rs:64:9
    |
64  |     Err(PgError::into_source())
    |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^-- an argument of type `postgres::Error` is missing
    |
note: method defined here
   --> /home/afidegnum/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/tokio-postgres-0.7.10/src/error/mod.rs:417:12
    |
417 |     pub fn into_source(self) -> Option<Box<dyn error::Error + Sync + Send>> {
    |            ^^^^^^^^^^^
help: provide the argument
    |
64  |     Err(PgError::into_source(/* postgres::Error */))
    |                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

error[E0308]: mismatched types
   --> src/main.rs:64:9
    |
64  |     Err(PgError::into_source())
    |     --- ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `Error`, found `Option<Box<...>>`
    |     |
    |     arguments to this enum variant are incorrect
    |
    = note: expected struct `postgres::Error`
                 found enum `Option<Box<(dyn std::error::Error + Send + Sync + 'static)>>`
help: the type constructed contains `Option<Box<(dyn std::error::Error + Send + Sync + 'static)>>` due to the type of the argument passed
   --> src/main.rs:64:5
    |
64  |     Err(PgError::into_source())
    |     ^^^^----------------------^
    |         |
    |         this argument influences the type of `Err`
note: tuple variant defined here
   --> /home/afidegnum/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/core/src/result.rs:511:5
    |
511 |     Err(#[stable(feature = "rust1", since = "1.0.0")] E),
    |     ^^^
```

Using `std::io::Error` also didn't help out.

Comment: You can't create a `postgres::error::Error` of your own, you should create your own error enum instead.

Comment: There's really no reason to include so much of the SQL we can't run anyways, you should reduce your example to a [mre] including only the bare minimum code needed to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @cafce25, ok, let me trim out the query. Can you please post a snippet of error Enum?

Comment: Uhm it's just a regular enum you use for your errors: `pub enum Error { NoRows, PgError(PgError), ...}` and probably implement `Display`, `std::error::Error` and `From<PgError>` for it.

Comment: You can use [`thiserror`](https://crates.io/crates/thiserror) to make it easier to create you custom error enum, or [`anyhow`](https://crates.io/crates/anyhow) if you don't care what error type your functions return, you just want it to be easy.

Comment: @Jmb, ok, thanks,